# Segfault on ncurses library

Tags: c, printing, segmentation-fault, ncurses

So I've been running upon this segfault error while im trying to draw a litte room using ncurses

GDB Output:

```
0x00007ffff76477c5 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff7649558 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff764b760 in malloc () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#3  0x00007ffff7bcb924 in _nc_printf_string ()
   from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.5
#4  0x00007ffff7bc70af in vwprintw ()
   from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.5
#5  0x00007ffff7bc7358 in mvwprintw ()
   from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.5
#6  0x0000000000401037 in drawRooms (rooms=0x6130b0) at src/draw.c:69
#7  0x0000000000400e88 in drawBoard (p=0x613040, 
filepath=0x401bf4 "assets/input.txt") at src/draw.c:28
#8  0x0000000000400d7b in run (name=0x604010 "name", 
path=0x401bf4 "assets/input.txt") at src/rogue.c:19
#9  0x0000000000400d3c in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe038) at src/main.c:24
```

The code at line 69 in the drawRooms function is:

```
mvwprintw (stdscr, pos.y, pos.x + x, "-");
```

Using gdb I checked the values of pos.y, pos.x and x and got it's values. Therefore I think its the actual mvwprintw function in ncurses. I think. This error was happening in another function where I'm drawing but I just commented it out in hopes of figuring it out later. However it started happening here

What can I do to fix this?

EDIT:

```
void drawRooms(Room * rooms)
{
  int t = 0;

  int x = 0, y = 0;
  Position pos;

  for(t=0;t<MAX_RM_AMNT;t++)
  {
    pos = rooms[t].pos;    
    for(x=0;x<rooms[t].width;x++) // the top/bottom
    {
      mvwprintw (stdscr, pos.y, pos.x + x, "-"); //segfaults here and any other mvwprintw
      mvwprintw (stdscr, pos.y+rooms[t].height, pos.x + x, "-");
    }

    for(y=1;y<rooms[t].height;y++)
    {
      mvwprintw (stdscr, pos.y+y, pos.x, "|");
      mvwprintw (stdscr, pos.y+y, pos.x+rooms[t].width, "|");
    }
  }    

  refresh();
  return;
}
```

EDIT 2:

Doing a simple

```
mvwprintw(stdscr, 0,0,"X");
```

Instead of the original code, still creates a segfault

Comment: a segmentation fault in `malloc` usually means your heap is corrupted. You'll have to go over all of your code to make sure you never corrupt the heap (by writing beyond the bounds of an allocated memory block eg.).

Comment: valgrind can help with analysis.  Because there is no source code in this question, it is impossible for others to point out the likely cause of the problem.

Comment: @ThomasDickey i added the function where its crashing

Comment: @ThomasDickey I tried a simple mvwprintw (stdscr, 0, 0, "X"); and its crashing on that too

Comment: @Exikle : memory corruption can be introduced anywhere in your code - it isn't necessarily close to where it causes issues (eg. a segmentation fault). You really need to check all of your code (and as pointed out by Thomas Dickey, tools like valgrind can help you with that).